# When downloading LEDE, what is the LUCI build?

Tags: openwrt, lede

I'm trying to download [LEDE for Linksys DD-WRT1900ac](https://downloads.lede-project.org/releases/packages-17.01/arm_cortex-a9_vfpv3/). There are multiple builds available, one of them is labeled `luci` I'm wondering what that means, the rest of them are pretty logical: `networking`, `telephony` etc.

Answer (score 0):

LEDE is a fork of OpenWRT. Luci is the name of the [graphical theme and webserver bundle](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/luci.essentials).